# Display UIAlert from one class onto the currently viewed Controller Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

Im reading a value from Firebase using swift and then continue observing it while the user navigates the rest of the app. When the value changes it displays an alert, but this to happen no matter what view controller youre on. Essentially, id like to be able to display this alert on any view controller despite not being on the one presenting it.

Any help?

```
 self.UserIsBlocked(userId: id){(blocked, value, success) in
        if success == true {
            if blocked == true {
                let time = String(describing: value)
                let blocked = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Message to be displayed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                self.present(blocked, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let ban = (value as! Int) * 60
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(ban)){
                    blocked.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit:
When I try                     `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(blocked, animated: true, completion: nil)`  get this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x1028ad800> on <Greek_Life.LoginController: 0x103012400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController? was simply presenting the initial view controller so in the drop down I saw UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.currentViewController() and this worked

Comment: There's no such method as `UIWindow currentViewController`. If you have one you must have written it or some library you are using added it in an extension.

Comment: I didnt make it and i only have UIKIt imported so nope. it exists

Comment: It is defined by returning the top view controller in the stack of view controllers

Comment: As of iOS 11.2 there is no such method on `UIWindow` or any other class provided by Apple. It's definitely something in your project or something used by your project.